# Simplify matching values while comparing two sorted sets

Tags: beginner, algorithm

This is in Star Basic but most likely quite a few languages would have similar structure.

I am comparing rows in two sorted sheets. I have a comparison function which returns -1 / 0 / 1 similarly to `StrComp()` depending whether the row passed as the first argument is before / equal / after the row passed as the second argument. So:

```
    For currentRow = 1 to n
        Do
            compareRow = myCompareRow( currentRow, TemplateRow )
            before = compareRow < 0
            If before Then 
                templateRow = templateRow + 1
            End If
        Loop While templateRow <= templateBottom and before
        If compareRow = 0 Then
            REM we have a match.
        Else
            REM we do not have a match.
        End If
    Next
```

I am wondering whether this could be simplified. (Why I am having distant fizzbuzz feelings.)

Answer (score 1):

## OBOB

This doesn't seem right.

```
            If before Then 
                templateRow = templateRow + 1
            End If
        Loop While templateRow <= templateBottom and before
```

The `While` condition lets us go past the template bottom.

A very simple guard would be

```
            If before and templateRow < templateBottom Then
```

This ensures the index remains valid.

## loop invariant

Your source code would be easier to read if you explicitly called
out the condition you strive to preserve:

> Currently indexed row is always >= template row upon exiting the loop.

You could phrase that as a REMark / comment.
But better to phrase it as `assert compareRow > -1`,
throwing a fatal error if it's not satisfied.

## index names

Consider using the conventional, short, {`i`, `j`} identifiers
for indexing {sheet, template}.

Comment: Yeah I knew it'll overrun https://i.imgur.com/ziQsmVJ.png I forgot to mention I did consider that but didn't add the condition because it'd make even uglier :/ that assert is a great idea, thanks! however it doesn't seem like Star Basic has an assert like that?